# Perl Regex to ignore blank line

Tags: regex, perl

I have a perl expression which displays the numeric digit from the last line of thetext file. My perl expression is as below

```
tail -1 new.txt | perl -e  'while (<>) {s/----//; s/:.*$//; print "$_\n" ;}'
```

which results as `109`, and new.txt is:

```
----109:new change
no blank lines below this
```

Now how can I change the expression so that even if it finds blank lines below `----109:new change` it skips them and returns `109` only?

My new.txt looks like as below

```
Create TAble <TAble name>

----109:new change1

Update Table <TAble name>

----110:new change2

Drop table <tablename>

----111:new change3
     <empty line>  
     <empty line>
```

as per this text file it should give 111 as result though there are many blank lines after last non empty line

Summary of my requirement is

I need to display 111 as a result no matter how many blank lines and whitespaces are there in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will print number only when one found after `----`,

```
tail -1 new.txt | perl -lne 'print $1 if /----(\d+)/'
```

- `-l` implicit line chomp, and adds newline after `print`
- `-n` implicit `while(<>){  }` loop around code

update: to pick only last number,

```
perl -lne '$num =$1 if /----(\d+)/ }{print $num' new.txt
```

Comment: i have so many ---- in my text file . i want to pick the last one even if there are blank lines after that

Comment: it is giving me the blank line now

Comment: Create TAble <TAble name>

----109:new change1

Update Table <TAble name>

----110:new change2

Drop table <tablename>

----111:new change3

Comment: @user3793536 post the above comment in your question.

Comment: nopes.. didn't work .. evertime i get blank line .. i added blank lines and cheked there are no white spaces

Comment: @sapnaO did you copy/paste of `perl -lne '$num =$1 if /----(\d+)/ }{print $num' new.txt`?

Comment: yeah .. it works.. i added so many blank lines in the end.. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are saying you need to process last non-empty line. This is how you get it:

```
tac new.txt | sed -e '/./,$!d' | head -n 1
```

You can pipe it to your perl command. Or to e.g. this one:

```
| perl -pe 's/\D*(\d+):.*/$1/'
```

Putting all together:

```
tac new.txt | sed -e '/./,$!d' | head -n 1 | perl -pe 's/\D*(\d+):.*/$1/'
```

returns `111` for your provided sample.

Comment: Thanks but it is not giving me any result

Comment: Could you try the first part only and see if it gets any result?

Comment: it just moves to next line.no result

Comment: @user3793536 Could you provide sample content of new.txt file then? Thanks.

Comment: Create TAble <TAble name>

----109:new change1

Update Table <TAble name>

----110:new change2

Drop table <tablename>

----111:new change3

Comment: It doesn't show newlines here. Please edit your question, put it there and prefix each line of the file content with 4 spaces.

Comment: @user3793536 I've editted the answer. Please re-run. If it still wouldn't work, might it be that your "empty" lines at the end of file contain whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Add `next unless $_;` into your loop to skill completely empty lines. However tail -1 will only ever give you the last line so you would need to start further back in the file, like this:

```
tail -5 new.txt | perl -e  'while (<>) {next unless $_; s/----//; s/:.*$//; $last=$_; } print "$last\n";'
```

Replace -5 with the largest number of empty line you could have. This will print the last number seen in the file.

Comment: 3-4 empty lines i am getting as a result

Comment: How can that be? The above perl code contains only one print statement outside the loop

Comment: Just noting that `next unless $_` works well in this case, but fundamentally ignores any lines that have a false value i.e. would ignore lines containing numeric 0. An alternative could be `next if /^\s*$/`.